# Can't parse data from the array received thanks FQL query

Tags: parsing, facebook-fql

I have a problem while fetching data from an array that I obtain with a fql query.
The data that I receive has this structure:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "Just Café Pacini",
      "can_post": true,
      "page_id": 401836073222759,
    },``
    {....},
    {....},
]
}
```

I'm working with the php SDK and I'm trying to receive some informations about several pages.
I've tried with `foreach($ret_obj['data'] as $single_obj)` as usual but php tells me that there's no index "data".

I'm sure that facebook doesn't return any error.

Answer (score -1):

first you must call json_decode($ret_obj) to get a php array
 then you can call foreach to iterate